# Woothemes per bottle and case pricing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

Okay so I am creating a woo commerce website and the point of website is to order wine.

My question is the following..

I would like 2 prices displayed.. one of the prices displayed would be per bottle and the other one would be cases which could vary from 6,12 etc.

When you order wine, you can only order cases, the per bottle listed price is only for search result purposes only.

I have done a variety of woocommerce php editing over the last couple days that have got me no where ( I can expand if necessary )

If someone who has had experience in this type of website can give me a push in the right direction that would be appreciated

I have found some useful plugins for this matter but I am not sure if they can target my specific need.

http://www.woothemes.com/products/minmax-quantities/

http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2013/09/09/woocommerce-product-quantity-dropdown/

Comment: So you can never order a bottle? Why not just make the case the product (and product price = case price) and then add the bottle price in the product description?

Comment: When the user does a price search it will be via bottle and some products contain quantities of 6 and 13

Comment: That makes things rather complicated. I would probably just add a custom field to the "case" product that holds the price per bottle, and write my own search by price function that uses that meta value rather than the product price (which would be by case).

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/minmax-quantities/ if I ignore the whole search thing for now. would this plugin basically do what I would like it to?

Comment: I think so - it does allow you to force users to buy things in factors of X (so you can make them only buy 6, 12, 18 bottles instead of increments of 1 bottle), but if the case price isn't always exactly equal to (bottle price * bottles per case) you will have some issues.

Comment: okay thanks for your help. Yeah Ill try to figure out how to have it displayed by price but you can only order cases

Comment: Obviously way late, but to follow up per-case pricing could be handled via [Product Bundles](https://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/) or [Mix and Match Products](https://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/)